# Making REST API Requests (GET/POST/PUT/DELET) in c# console

Tags: rest, api, .net-core

I want to connect from **.NET CORE** to a **Rest API** that will do the operation **(GET/POST/PUT/DELETE)**  and get the answer, but I do not know how

Comment: Microsoft has a [fairly good example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) in its documentation on exactly that. Note however, that this is a typical pseudo-REST client that actually deserves more to be called RPC than REST ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) class available in .NET Core. This class contains methods for all of the HTTP operations you mentioned (such as PostAsJson). It will also handle any object-to-Json serialisation for you.